# Why this Hibernate JPQL query can't work?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpql

I am absolutly new in **Hibernate** and in **JPQL** queries and I have some problem trying to actuate the following query. The situation is the following one, I have:

1) An entity class named **KMCountryArea** that map the **KM_COUNTRY_AREA** table on my database:

```
@NamedQueries({
        //@NamedQuery(name = "kmCountryListByName", query = "SELECT c FROM KMCountryArea c WHERE c.nomeFolder  = :nomeFolder order by c.idCountryArea")
        @NamedQuery(name = "kmCountryListByName", query = "SELECT c FROM KMCountryArea c WHERE c.nomeFolder  = :nomeFolder order by c.idCountryArea")
})

/*@NamedQuery(name = "kmCountryListByName", query = "SELECT country FROM KMCountryArea country WHERE country.nomeFolder  = :nomeFolder order by country.idCountry")*/

@Entity
@Table(name = "KM_COUNTRY_AREA")
public class KMCountryArea implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long idCountryArea;

    @Column(name = "nomeFolder")
    private String nomeFolder;

    //@Column(name = "country")
    //@OneToOne(mappedBy = "country", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OneToOne
    private KMCountry country;

    public Long getIdCountryArea() {
        return idCountryArea;
    }

    public void setIdCountryArea(Long idCountryArea) {
        this.idCountryArea = idCountryArea;
    }

    public String getNomeFolder() {
        return nomeFolder;
    }

    public void setNomeFolder(String nomeFolder) {
        this.nomeFolder = nomeFolder;
    }

    public KMCountry getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(KMCountry country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
}
```

As you can see this class and the related table have only 3 fields:

- The **row id**:

  ```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long idCountryArea;
  ```
- A **nomeFolder** String that match with the **nomeFolder** column on the table:

  ```
  @Column(name = "nomeFolder")
  private String nomeFolder;
  ```
- The **KMCountry country** that represent a **one to one** relation with another **KMCountry** entity class definied into my project that itself have definied this field as id **private Long idCountry;**

  ```
  @OneToOne
  private KMCountry country;
  ```

Infact this Hibernate entity class correctly generate the **KM_COUNTRY** table inside my database, this is the **KM_COUNTRY** table fields that I see inside the DB:

```
COLUMN NAME          DATA_TYPE           NULLABLE    DATA_DEFAULT   COLUMN_ID
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IDCOUNTRYAREA        NUMBER(19,0)          No           (null)             1    
NOMEFOLDER           VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)    Yes          (null)             2    
COUNTRY_IDCOUNTRY    NUMBER(19,0)          Yes          (null)             3
```

I think that it is correct because it seems to me that the 3 fields definied into the **KMCountryArea** entity class are correctly mapped inside the **KM_COUNTRY** table.

So I have manually inserted a row inside the **KM_COUNTRY** table (by an insert query, and performing this simple select query (inside the Oracle SQL Developer that is the DBMS IDE):

```
select * from KM_COUNTRY_AREA where nomefolder = 'BRAZIL';
```

I obtain the following correct result:

```
IDCOUNTRYAREA        NOMEFOLDER      COUNTRY_IDCOUNTRY
------------------------------------------------------------
     2                 BRAZIL              715
```

Now I have to do something like this query using JPQL but instead obtain a set of rows (in the previous case it is only one but I can obtain more rows) I want obtain the list of the **KMCountry** object having the definied id (inside the entity) equals to the **COUNTRY_IDCOUNTRY** value.

So, as you can see, I implemented this **JPQL named query**:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "kmCountryListByName", query = "SELECT c FROM KMCountryArea c WHERE c.nomeFolder  = :nomeFolder order by c.idCountryArea")
```

Then, in my project, I have definied the DAO service that perform the previous query, implementing this concrete class:

```
@Repository("kmCountryAreaService")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public class KMCountryAreaServiceImpl extends AbstractService implements KMCountryAreaService {

    public List<KMCountry> getCountryListByName(String folderName){
        List<KMCountry> list = getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQuery("kmCountryListByName");
        return list;
    }

}
```

As you can see it is definied as a Spring repository and implements a **KMCountryAreaService** interface in wich I simply list the CRUD implmented method (at this stage of works exist only the **getCountryListByName()**)

Ok then in my code (into an action class) I perform this operation:

```
List<KMCountry> kmCountryListAssociated = kmCountryAreaService.getCountryListByName("BRAZIL", folderName);
```

So I expect to retrieve the list of **KMCountry** object that into the **KM_COUNTRY** table have the **NOMEFOLDER** field value equals to **BRAZIL**.

But it don't works, infact, using the debugger, I see that the execution go into the **getCountryListByName()** method but when it try to perform this statment:

```
List<KMCountry> list = getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQuery("kmCountryListByName");
```

an exception is thrown (but its message it is not printed into the stacktrace).

What am I missing? How can I try to solve this issue? I am going crazy trying to understand what is wrong.

Tnx

**EDIT-1**:

I have modified the **getCountryListByName()** method to track the excpetion, now my method is:

```
public List<KMCountry> getCountryListByName(String nomeFolder) {

    List<KMCountry> list = null;

    try{
        list = getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQuery("kmCountryListByName", nomeFolder);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return list;
}
```

and the obtained excpetion is:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based!
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.ParameterMetadata.getOrdinalParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadata.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.ParameterMetadata.getOrdinalParameterExpectedType(ParameterMetadata.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.determineType(AbstractQueryImpl.java:397)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:369)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$33.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:985)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$33.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.findByNamedQuery(HibernateTemplate.java:979)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.findByNamedQuery(HibernateTemplate.java:975)
    at egp.prc.km.services.KMCountryAreaServiceImpl.getCountryListByName(KMCountryAreaServiceImpl.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy377.getCountryListByName(Unknown Source)
    at egp.prc.km.actions.countryArea.CountryAreaAction.showMultiSelectCountry(CountryAreaAction.java:205)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:452)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:291)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:254)
    at egp.prc.km.utils.interceptors.LiferayAjaxInterceptor.intercept(LiferayAjaxInterceptor.java:28)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:270)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:498)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.servlet.StrutsServlet.service(StrutsServlet.java:76)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not passing `folderName` into the query. Try this

```
List<KMCountry> list = getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam("kmCountryListByName", "nomeFolder", folderName);
```

Comment: I tryied, to do as you suggest but it seems that I obtain a throws java.lang.Exception

Comment: Can you post the exception?

Comment: The problem is that the exception message is not printed into the stackrace and I can't understand why

Comment: Can you debug the code, line by line, and see in which line it breaks? Then, surround that line with `try - catch` block and print the stack trace in `catch` with `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: Ok, I have done as you suggested, I edited my original post inserting at the end of it the obtained exception details. Tnx so much for your help and for your time

Comment: I think I know what's the problem, updated the answer.

Comment: Tnx, it seems work. I understand that now I am combine the field name with its value...but why in some other queries inside my projects (that take parameters) it works without have to use the findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam() method? It do it automatically...

Comment: Can't tell without seeing the code, but possible reasons are that it works on queries that are not named queries, or maybe you use positional parameters (`?1`) instead of named parameters (`:param`).

Comment: what do you mean? I posted the code of my named query into the original post and I use named parameters :nomeFolder in it and not parameters like ?1

Comment: I was referring to the other queries you mention that work without `findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam`.